# How to get the current text in meteor-sharejs ace editor

Tags: meteor, ace-editor, sharejs

Im trying to make a little markdown editor with a panel that shows the rendered markdown.  My problem is dont seem to be able to get the current content, it always one step behind.  Ive used

return ace.edit("editor").getValue();

Is there a way to bind to the object that the editor is using?

Comment: What do you mean by behind one step? Where in the application are you trying to get the value?

Comment: I have a template with the Ace editor and a {{markdown}} template. There is a helper for the content. 
Template.zenoEditor.helpers
({
    docid: function () {
        return Session.get("document");
    },
    document: function () {
        return ace.edit("editor").getValue();
    }
});
When I select a document from the list the markdown shows the last one selected not the current one. Im using the example that comes with the package.

Comment: Ive uploaded it here http://zeno.meteor.com/zeno-editor, you can see how the rendered markdown is for the last selected item.

Comment: code is here https://github.com/Phils-Ideas/zeno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems pretty clear that the `getValue()` is running before the DOM has a chance to update reactively, so it's always grabbing the value that was previously selected. You need to wrap that line in a Tracker.afterFlush:

```
document: function () {
  Tracker.afterFlush(function(){
    return ace.edit("editor").getValue();
 });
}
```

Hopefully that will get things working! As an aside, I'm not sure why you are wrapping the `{{document}}` in `{{#with docId}}`, seems like it might be expecting a document property in the `Documents` object. Not sure if this is actually affecting anything, but seeing as you are directly pulling the `document` from the editor, it's a little confusing.

Comment: Thanx, I did something similar and called Tracker.flush() after the docId is changed.  I removed the {{#with docid}} too.